# How to use a variable from one function in the other function in Django Views

Tags: python, django

I have 2 functions:

The 1 function checks the URL for scheme:

```
def checkurl(self):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'url' in request.POST:
        url = request.POST.get('url', '')
        if not url.startswith('http://') and not url.startswith('https://'):
            url = "https://" + url
    return url
```

The 2 function should use the url variable. But it says "name 'url' is not defined". Here is the second function:

```
def tests(request):

    ##################################################
    # URL Parse: netloc, scheme
    ##################################################

    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    time = x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'url' in request.POST:
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}#headers

        # Set Width and Height

        width_get = request.POST.get('width', '')
        height_get = request.POST.get('height', '')
        if width_get is not None and width_get != '':
            width = width_get
        else:
            width = 1600
        if height_get is not None and height_get != '':
            height = height_get
        else:
            height = 1000

        if url is not None and url != '':

            url_parsed = urlparse(url)
            scheme = url_parsed.scheme
            netloc = url_parsed.netloc
            if netloc.startswith('www.'):
                netloc = netloc.replace('www.', '')
            image_path = "media/" + netloc + "-" + time + ".png"
            shot_path = "/media/" + netloc + "-" + time + ".png"
            path = "C:/WebDrivers/chromedriver.exe"
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
            driver.get(url)
            driver.set_window_size(width, height)
            driver.save_screenshot(image_path)
            screenshot = image_path
            driver.quit()
            var_dict = {
                'screenshot': screenshot,
                'shot_path':shot_path,
                'netloc':netloc,
                }
            return render(request, 'apptests/shots.html', var_dict)
    else:
        return render(request, 'apptests/shots.html')
```

How can I use the URL variable from the 1st function in my second function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not calling `checkurl` so when you do `if url is not None and url != '':`, the variable `url` is not defined yet.

you just need to add `url = checkurl()` before that line I think.

However, you will need to pass in `request` to that function instead of `self` as as far as I can tell from the code you've posted, `checkurl` doesn't seem to be a method on a class and you're using function based views for the `tests` view.

So, `checkurl` would be:

```
def checkurl(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'url' in request.POST:
        url = request.POST.get('url', '')
        if not url.startswith('http://') and not url.startswith('https://'):
            url = "https://" + url
        return url
```

Notice I've indented the `return url`. This is so that `url` is returned only if we have one. In your current `checkurl` function, if `if request.method == 'POST' and 'url' in request.POST:` is false, you'll be trying to return a variable that doesn't exist (it's only defined in the scope of that if statement). So now the function will just return `None` if that condition is not met.

Then you just need to import that function into your `views.py` file (if it's in a separate file), and call it above that `if` statement:

```
url = checkurl(request)

if url is not None and url != '':
    ...
```